# Addon/feature to let me change the density of the retopology?

Tags: retopology

So basically I’m working on this model with very low detail in the body but very high detail in the mouth. I was hoping to retopologize with a tool or addon instead of doing it by hand but whenever I do the density is spread equally, giving the body an unnecessary amount of faces and the mouth far too few.
Is there a feature, method, or addon to somehow control the density when retopologizing? Perhaps a way to retopo the head and body separately then put them back together without ruining the mesh?
I really don’t want to have to retopo the head myself, as the mouth would be grueling, which is why I’m desperate for an alternative.

Comment: Here are some tools to retopo, I don't know if this will answer: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CviZw41IbMg

Answer (score 1):

I reckon you really mean automatic remeshing more than retopology? Blender's remeshing tools are mostly to equalize the density but don't really adapt to the actual shape. Some third party addons and tools do that a bit better, such as [wjakob/instant-meshes](https://github.com/wjakob/instant-meshes) or even [Quad Remesher](https://exoside.com/quadremesher/) if you can afford it.

But otherwise, if your goal is to have topology really adapted to your mesh, both in density and shape definition, it's remains pretty hard to beat manual topology:
I don't think I've seen an automated remesh tool that allows different densities in different areas of the same mesh.

However, if you are willing to retopologize the head and body separately and then combine them together, you can do so, though you will still have to do the joint topology manually.

1. Separate the head and body into two objects (edit mode > select > <kbd>P</kbd> > separate by selection)
2. Back in object mode, remesh your object with any method you like (I'd suggest the above-mentioned addons, it will be easier to work with the geometry they produce).
3. Join the objects together (select both object, <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> > Join
4. You will have only the junction area topology to do.

It's a bit dirty, but it works.

There are a few addons that can help you in manual retopology too:

- [RetopoFlow 3](https://blendermarket.com/products/retopoflow?ref=247) free ([here](https://github.com/CGCookie/retopoflow/releases))
- [SpeedRetopo](https://pitiwazou-1.gumroad.com/l/speedretopo)